# Conditional Formatting not being applied

Tags: vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm trying to apply rules to columns of a template if certain cells are populated, the formatting would then use the value/address for the formula. I'm kind of lost at this point as everything else is in working order and I'm not getting any errors. The QAcol is generated earlier in the code for populating these cells. Any attempt at specifying a sheet to the conditional format range results in an object defined error, and I'm not sure why.

```
Dim CFQcol As Integer
Dim j As Integer


wb.Sheets("QA Data").Activate
row = 0
col = 0

For CFQcol = 17 To QAcol
    If IsEmpty(wb.Sheets("QA Data").Cells(3, CFQcol)) = False And InStr(wb.Sheets("QA Data").Cells(3, CFQcol).Value, "Repo") = 0 Then
        j = 1
        If IsEmpty(wb.Sheets("QA Data").Cells(4, CFQcol)) = False Then
            Range(Cells(11, CFQcol), Cells(10000, CFQcol)).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:=Cells(4, CFQcol).Address
            Range(Cells(11, CFQcol), Cells(10000, CFQcol)).FormatConditions(j).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            j = j + 1
            End If
        If IsEmpty(wb.Sheets("QA Data").Cells(7, CFQcol)) = False Then
            Range(Cells(11, CFQcol), Cells(10000, CFQcol)).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:=Cells(7, CFQcol).Address
            Range(Cells(11, CFQcol), Cells(10000, CFQcol)).FormatConditions(j).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 200)
            j = j + 1
            End If
        If IsEmpty(wb.Sheets("QA Data").Cells(5, CFQcol)) = False Then
            Range(Cells(11, CFQcol), Cells(10000, CFQcol)).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:=Cells(5, CFQcol).Address
            Range(Cells(11, CFQcol), Cells(10000, CFQcol)).FormatConditions(j).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            j = j + 1
            End If
        If IsEmpty(wb.Sheets("QA Data").Cells(8, CFQcol)) = False Then
            Range(Cells(11, CFQcol), Cells(10000, CFQcol)).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:=Cells(8, CFQcol).Address
            Range(Cells(11, CFQcol), Cells(10000, CFQcol)).FormatConditions(j).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 200)
            End If
    End If
Next
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Dont you need to change address to relative? .Address(False, False)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range uses the active sheet by default. You are mixing implicit and explicit references. You should always use explicit references when you can. You never have to `.Activate` unless you are moving the view for the user. You're missing a `j = j + 1` on the last block. Let's move the `j = 1` outside the loop because you are going to be adding more conditional formats each time.

**NOTE: Adding a large number of conditional formats is a bad idea. It will slow down your workbook and make it unusable at some point.**

When I ran my test code the format did change the text red. It's hard to tell if the code is doing what you want without seeing your data and a better idea of the end result.

```
Dim CFQcol As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim qaData As Worksheet
Set qaData = wb.Sheets("QA Data")

row = 0
col = 0
j = 1

For CFQcol = 17 To QAcol
    If Not IsEmpty(qaData.Cells(3, CFQcol)) And InStr(qaData.Cells(3, CFQcol).Value, "Repo") = 0 Then

        If Not IsEmpty(qaData.Cells(4, CFQcol)) Then
            With qaData.Range(Cells(11, CFQcol), Cells(10000, CFQcol))
                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:=qaData.Cells(4, CFQcol).Address
                .FormatConditions(j).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End With
            j = j + 1
        End If
        
        If Not IsEmpty(qaData.Cells(7, CFQcol)) Then
            With qaData.Range(Cells(11, CFQcol), Cells(10000, CFQcol))
                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:=qaData.Cells(7, CFQcol).Address
                .FormatConditions(j).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 200)
            End With
            j = j + 1
        End If
        
        If Not IsEmpty(qaData.Cells(5, CFQcol)) Then
            With qaData.Range(Cells(11, CFQcol), Cells(10000, CFQcol))
                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:=qaData.Cells(5, CFQcol).Address
                .FormatConditions(j).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End With
            j = j + 1
        End If
        
        If Not IsEmpty(qaData.Cells(8, CFQcol)) Then
            With qaData.Range(Cells(11, CFQcol), Cells(10000, CFQcol))
                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:=qaData.Cells(8, CFQcol).Address
                .FormatConditions(j).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 200)
            End With
            j = j + 1
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks! This nearly works for me, I had to add the address to the cells in the range though. Maybe different excel versions? `With qaData.Range(Cells(11, CFQcol).Address, Cells(10000, CFQcol).Address)` Any idea how to stop conditional formatting from putting double quotes around my formula address? It's currently reporting `="$A$1"` which nulls any number that would be at the address.

Comment: I don't think this code is the reason. Try debugging. Run line by line and see what each line does.